# Очистить ячейки, значения которых отсутствуют в списке

Tags: vba

Есть столбец C  и в нем с 3 по 25 ряд уже вписанны слова - Dear,Meal,Run. Как же прописать макрос, который будет удалять слова другие то есть если колонна содержит (вручную вписать какое -то другое слово или цифру( не важно)) то excel просто удалит это значение.  Слова в этой колонне должны быть только эти на другие clearcontent
Код который не работает(

```
Sub dd()
For i = 1 To 20
If Cells(i, 3).Value <> "Deal" Or "Meal" Or "Run" Then
Cells(i, 20).ClearContents
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Уточните задачу. В столбце 3 удалять слова, которые не равны трем показанным. То есть удалять все, которые не попали в список... И тут же пишете: удалять только слова, указанные вручную... В ячейках по одному слову или по несколько? Столбец 20 - что с ним делать? Или искать в третьем, удалять в 20, как в коде? В общем, уточните, пожалуйста.

Comment: @vikttur " В столбце 3 удалять слова, которые не равны трем показанным" - да, " не попали в список..." не попали в интервал(1 до 20)  "В ячейках по одному слову или по несколько?" - по одному

Comment: >>столбец C и в нем с 3 по 25 ряд. В комментарии - 1-20. Где правда?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Неправильный синтаксис проверки. Правильно:

```
If Cells(i, 3).Value <> "Deal" Or Cells(i, 3).Value <> "Meal" Or Cells(i, 3).Value <> "Run" Then
```

Так правильно с точки зрения синтаксиса, но неправильно логически. Применяется оператор *Or* (*ИЛИ*). При такой записи не может быть результата *False*.

Примеры.

В ячейке слово "*Deal*":

```
"Deal" <> "Deal" Or "Deal" <> "Meal" = False + True = True
```

В ячейке слво "*Excel*":

```
"Excel" <> "Deal" Or "Excel" <> "Meal" = True + True = True
```

В этом случае нужно применять оператор *And* (*И*).

===========================

Просматриваем строки с 3 по 25. Если в ячейке столбца С значение не равно указанным, очищаем ячейку.  Вместо *And* - каскад *If*, позволяющий отрезать лишние вычисления.

```
Sub DelVal1()
Dim i As Long
    For i = 3 To 25' цикл по строкам
        If Cells(i, 3).Value <> "Deal" Then
            If Cells(i, 3).Value <> "Meal" Then
                If Cells(i, 3).Value <> "Run" Then Cells(i, 3).ClearContents
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Значение ячейки можно искать в тексте, составленном из искомых слов:

```
Sub DelVal2()
Dim i As Long
    For i = 3 To 25
        If Not ("DealMealRun" Like "*" & Cells(i, 3).Value & "*") Then _
                                            Cells(i, 3).ClearContents
    Next i
End Sub
```

Если слов много, имеет смысл занести их в массив:

```
Sub DelVal3()
Dim ArrVal()
Dim i As Long, j As Long
    ArrVal = Array("Deal", "Meal", "Run") ' значения в массив

    For i = 3 To 25 ' цикл по строкам
        For j = 0 To UBound(ArrVal) ' цикл по массиву
            If Cells(i, 3).Value = ArrVal(j) Then Exit For
        Next j

        ' ни одно не найдено - очищаем ячейку
        If j = UBound(ArrVal) + 1 Then Cells(i, 3).ClearContents
    Next i
End Sub
```